# Normals are right but shading is still weird

Tags: normals

I've checked the normals and everything and I still don't understand why this is happening :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know what's causing this but when I delete all the faces and refill them the problem is gone so there must be some other datas that I missed?

The blend file is here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove custom split normals in mesh data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem.