# when I apply the scale, it breaks my shading

Tags: shaders, normals, mirror, mirror-modifier, smooth

when I mirror this object shading looks good, but when I apply the scale shading breaks and I have no idea how to fix it. I already tried recalculating normals.
[image: shading works]

[image: shading is broken]

Normals are flipped correctly.
[image: normals are flipped correctly]

[image]

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: the vertex normals might be wrong even if the face normals are correct

Comment: I added file at the bottom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normals are right but shading is still weird](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276570/normals-are-right-but-shading-is-still-weird)

Comment: not really, it does fix the top but breaks everything else

Comment: Clear custom normal data, autosmooth at 40°